# Выполнить проверку на доступ к элементам TDBRadioGroup

Tags: delphi, база-данных, firebird

Как организовать проверку на доступ к элементу TDBRadioGroup, а главное в каком месте, чтоб во время переоткрытия DataSet не летела ошибка «List index out of bounds (-1)».

```
procedure TFMain.dbrgStatisticaChange(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if (cbMethodSort.ItemIndex = 4)
    and (dbrgStatistica.ItemIndex = 0) then
    begin
        ibdsWord.Close; //<- летит ошибка
        ibdsWord.SelectSQL.Clear;
        ibdsWord.SelectSQL.Add(<<ARequire>>);
        ibdsWord.FetchAll;
        ibdsWord.Open;
        ibdsWord.First;
    end
end;
```

Comment: Где то у вас видимо происходит обращение к несуществующему элементу combobox'a.

Comment: Это я знаю, это выкидывает TDBRadioGroup (dbrgStatistica). Я ущел от этой проблемы, просто ставя после "begin", dbrgStatistica.Enabled := false;   
и перед "end", dbrgStatistica.Enabled := true;   
но как сказали - это не совсем правильно

Comment: Я чего-то не пойму, объясните, пожалуйста: в Item dbrgStatisticaChange, два значения "0" и "1", если выбираешь "0" (как в примере), вылазит ошибка. Если в примере заменить на (dbrgStatistica.ItemIndex = 1) (т.е. срабатывание при выборе элемента под №1), то все хорошо. Как будто что-то настоятельно индекс уменьшает на один.   
Или не так?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

После "Begin"
"вырубил" отображение изменений всем ассоциированным чувствительных к данным компонентам (как написано в пояснении к этому методу),

```
 ibdsWord.DisableControls;
```

а перед "end" - включил -

```
"ibdsWord.EnableControls;"
```